# Zxing and Xamarin forms

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms, zxing

I' makeing an app in xamarin forms, All the stuff that it must make wark quite good, Now I'm trying to make it a little more nice.

The app now make a listview of article (code and descriprion only) getting them from an API on my server, when I tap on an item of the list view, it show more information and the price of that article.
I have installed the Zxing package to read directly the ean_code and skip the listview.
The API from the server work (tryed with Postman), but On the app it gime me an error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToEscape"

This is the code of the page where I insert the filter for the search or I click to read the Ean_code:

```
    public void TapArticolo(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Articolo Articolo_selezionato = (Articolo) ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem; //Link the tapped Item to the class variabile
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SchedaArticoloPage(Articolo_selezionato)); // Call the new page passing the class like parameter (Only Cod_articolo and Descr_1)
    }

    private void Button_Ean_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scan = new ZXingScannerPage();
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(scan);
        scan.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    Articolo Articolo_selezionato = new Articolo(); // Initialize the Class 
                    Articolo_selezionato.Ean_code = result.ToString(); // Write the Ean code inside the class
                    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SchedaArticoloPage(Articolo_selezionato));  // Call the new page passing the class like parameter (Only Ean_Code)
                });
        };
     
    }
```

This is the page that must show the detailed data after the collect:

```
public partial class SchedaArticoloPage : ContentPage
{
    public SchedaArticoloPage(Articolo Articolo_selezionato)
    {
        var SchedaArticoloViewModel = new SchedaArticoloViewModel();    //Initialize the ViewModel
        SchedaArticoloViewModel.Articolo_selezionato = Articolo_selezionato;  //Link the given Parameter to the class of the viewModel
        if (Articolo_selezionato.Cod_articolo != null) SchedaArticoloViewModel.Dati_articolo.Execute(null);  // Execute in case of tap (only the Cod_articolo is present)
        if (Articolo_selezionato.Ean_code != null) SchedaArticoloViewModel.Dati_articolo_da_ean.Execute(null);  //Execute in case of Ean code Read (only Ean code present)
        SchedaArticoloViewModel.Listini_Articolo_command.Execute(null); // Retrive price whan all the record of the class are present
        BindingContext = SchedaArticoloViewModel;   //Bind the content
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

To end these are the api to collect the data from the server:

```
    public async Task<Articolo> GetAnagraficaArticolo(string AccessToken, string cod_articolo)
    {
        server = Settings.Server;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(server + "/api/Articolo?cod_articolo=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(cod_articolo));
        var Articolo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Articolo>(json);
        return Articolo;
    }

    public async Task<Articolo> GetAnagraficaArticoloDaEan(string AccessToken, string Ean_Code)
    {
        server = Settings.Server;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(server + "/api/Articolo?Ean_code=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(Ean_Code));
        var Articolo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Articolo>(json);
        return Articolo;
    }
```

With the normal code it work like a charm, with the ean_code it crash. I really don't know where is the mistake.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: which specific line is causing the exception?

Comment: @Jason var json = await client.GetStringAsync(server + "/api/Articolo?Ean_code=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(Ean_Code));

Comment: Or at least it seems it's that line

Comment: the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToEscape" would lead me to think that you are passing an null value to `Uri.EscapeUriString(Ean_Code)`

Comment: @Jason checked, the access token and the Ean_code are present. But I think that, also if the program break there, the problem is not there, course I have try also to copy the part that work (the part above with the cod_articolo) giving a fix parameter to check the rest of the program, and the program break the same. Also if the code is right (above it work)

Comment: the exception clearly indicates that you are passing a null to one of the calls to EscapeUriString.  Have you actually set a breakpoint on those two lines to verify?

Comment: I've set a breakpoint at that line and the variabile you can see it here: https://ibb.co/fDCBJ4J

Comment: If I proceed it give the error...

Comment: what if you just remove the call to EscapeUriString?

Comment: @Jason tryed... And also try to give a fix value. Same error. I can make a work around and change the interface, but I would like to know why it give me this error. I'm a Newby but I like to understand my mistake so I can avoid to make them again in future

Comment: there must be something else going on here - you're saying you get the exact same exception if you do this?  `var json = await client.GetStringAsync(server + "/api/Articolo?Ean_code=" + Ean_Code);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but changed the phone connected and it have start to work like it should.